# How do I POST urlencoded form data with HTTP?

Tags: php, mysql, angular, ionic-framework, http-post

I want to pass data from Ionic Form to Php file to MySql Database. I'm completely new to this...
This is my code to pass data from Ionic Form to Php File

[Please check this link for code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgXBo.png)

I tried debugging my code using alert

```
alert(url); //Output: http://localhost/ionic-php-sql/manage-data.php
alert(body); //Output: key=create&name=Test&description=Test
alert(options); //[object Object]
```

Whenever I alert(options) then it is displaying [object Object]. (I guess this is incorrect or there is some mistake).
I tried putting alert() inside

```
 this.http.post(url, body, { headers: headers }).subscribe((data) =>{}
```

Then it is not displaying alert popup.
Please check the code and tell me in case of any mistakes/changes.
Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Answer for this question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47467651/8923137)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like :

`alert(JSON.stringify(options));`

**Alert** does not show `object` in alert box, it only supports `string` types.

I'll suggest you to use `console.log(options)` and you can see them in browser console, with any type.

**console.log()** prints all type of data.

Comment: Thanks. Now it is showing => {"method":null,"headers":{"Content-Type":["application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"]},"body":null,"url":null,"withCredentials":null,"responseType":null} Please check if the code is wrong or some mistakes